# How do I prevent capturing these unwanted lines in multiline regex?

Tags: .net, regex

This is my text structure

```
@2015
CSV,,,,,sfs,sdf,s,,ssdf,sf

@2015
ABC|@##%@
BCD|||asdf|45d|t
DEF|||sdfgs|45d|t
EFG|||assdfgdf|45d|t


@2015
ABC|@##%@
ZXY|zz|rwe2342345|unwanted|

--------------

@2015
CSV,,,,,sfs,sdf,s,,ssdf,sf

@2015
ABC|@##%@
BCD|||asdf|45d|t
DEF|||sdfgs|45d|t
EFG|||assdfgdf|45d|t


@2015
ABC|@##%@
ZXY|zz|rwe2342345|wanted|

--------------

@2015
CSV,,,,,sfs,sdf,s,,ssdf,sf

@2015
ABC|@##%@
BCD|||asdf|45d|t
DEF|||sdfgs|45d|t
EFG|||assdfgdf|45d|t


@2015
ABC|@##%@
ZXY|zz|rwe2342345|unwanted|
```

And my RegEx so far

```
CSV(.*\n)+?ZXY.*\|wanted\|
```

Using TextCrawler I get this result (1 result found)  It is including the unwanted groups in between.

```
1) CSV,,,,,sfs,sdf,s,,ssdf,sf

@2015
ABC|@##%@
BCD|||asdf|45d|t
DEF|||sdfgs|45d|t
EFG|||assdfgdf|45d|t


@2015
ABC|@##%@
ZXY|zz|rwe2342345|unwanted|

--------------

@2015
CSV,,,,,sfs,sdf,s,,ssdf,sf

@2015
ABC|@##%@
BCD|||asdf|45d|t
DEF|||sdfgs|45d|t
EFG|||assdfgdf|45d|t


@2015
ABC|@##%@
ZXY|zz|rwe2342345|wanted|
```

I really just want to capture the groups that go from the CSV to a line ZXY containing the string |wanted| (non greedy match).  How can I modify my regex to accomplish this? I'm using .Net regular expressions.

EDIT: Expected result is one block of text like this

```
CSV,,,,,sfs,sdf,s,,ssdf,sf

@2015
ABC|@##%@
BCD|||asdf|45d|t
DEF|||sdfgs|45d|t
EFG|||assdfgdf|45d|t


@2015
ABC|@##%@
ZXY|zz|rwe2342345|wanted|
```

Comment: what if you split on your separators `--------------` then filter any matches from that?

Comment: So, this result you get should not be captured *at all*, right?

Comment: Your expected output is not really clear.

Comment: He wants it to match from the last occurrence of `CSV` to the line containing `|wanted|`, but it's matching the first occurrence of `CSV` because of RegEx.

Comment: @tenub wouldn't my results include unwanted blocks of text? I only want to extract specific blocks. If I split by the separator I will get everything

Comment: @stribizhev that's right the output sample I get is not what I want. It is capturing too much of the text, parts I don't want

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you require. You could clarify this a lot by showing the **expected** output.

Comment: The most simple way is to match the whole CSV block with an extra capture group for "wanted" or "unwanted" and simply ignore the "unwanted" in code

Comment: @sparkplug ok, added expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
CSV((?!\-{14})[\s\S])*?\|wanted\|
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fO1yJ5/1)

`((?!\-{14})[\s\S])*?` basically says any number of characters not preceded by 14 dashes (which is the section delimiter here). It's the negative lookahead `(?!\-{14})` that seals the deal